# What is the purpose of the path at the top of the window of a mounted .dmg file, and how can I remove it?

Tags: macos, dmg, macdeployqt

I recently created a .dmg for my application using [`macdeployqt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx-deployment.html#the-mac-deployment-tool). The application works fine on other Macs, but I noticed that the original location of the built .app is at the top of the window after double clicking on the .dmg:

[image: dmg screenshot]

This is visible even on other Macs, and I'd rather it not be, since it seems like irrelevant information for an end user. I tried looking at the .dmg with these commands:

```
cd /Volumes
hdiutil info
```

I got a bunch of output, where the relevant part seems to be at the end:

```
framework       : 444.50.16
driver          : 10.12v444.50.16
================================================
image-path      : /Users/mitch/dev/slate-releases/slate-v0.0.5-mac.dmg
image-alias     : /Users/mitch/dev/slate-releases/slate-v0.0.5-mac.dmg
shadow-path     : <none>
icon-path       : /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Resources/CDiskImage.icns
image-type      : UDIF read-only compressed (zlib)
system-image    : false
blockcount      : 97676
blocksize       : 512
writeable       : false
autodiskmount   : TRUE
removable       : TRUE
image-encrypted : false
mounting user   : mitch
mounting mode   : <unknown>
process ID      : 31262
/dev/disk2  GUID_partition_scheme   
/dev/disk2s1    [...]   /Volumes/:Users:mitch:dev:slate-qt5_10_isle_fw-Release:app:slate
```

Why is the original filename part of the .dmg, and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Volume Name**

What appears as the window title in your screenshot is the volume name of the .dmg.

**Create Short Volumen Name**

Easiest way to handle it would be the following:

- in Terminal `cd` to the path where you app resides
- call from there `macdeployqt <appname> -dmg`

Then a .dmg is then created, which has the name of the app as volume name.

**Example**

```
cd examples/basic/widgets/cd/darwin
macdeployqt widgets.app -dmg
```

gives:

[image: dmg name]

So actually the relative path when calling macdeployqt is used as volume name  for the .dmg.

You can't remove or change the volume name of an existing readonly .dmg.

If you would create your .dmg with Disk Utility (located under /Applications/Utilities) by <File/New Image/Blank Image...> you would enter a 'Name'. This name is the same as the volume name of the .dmg.

**Manual Conversion**

If you want to use a GUI application to create a new .dmg with a custom volume name from your existing read-only.dmg, you can do this as follows:

- create a new .dmg with correct name (this name is then shown as window title, we could use here e.g. 'SomeFancyName')
- choose as format 'Mac OS Extended (Journaled)'
- Encryption: 'none'
- Partitions: 'Single partition - GUID Partition Map'
- Image Format: 'read/write disk image'

Then:

- copy over the content of the original .dmg
- finally eject the image from finder
- use Disk Utility <Images/Convert...>
- choose your read/write image there
- save with 'Image Format': compressed

[image: custom name]

**Image Conversion using the Command Line**

If you need to do this regularly, it should be mentioned that hdiutil also offers image conversion via the command line, see:

```
man hdiutil
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. The first part about running macdeployqt in the same directory as the app is all I need, but it's great to know there are other options.